# Oracle Apex trigger issue

Tags: oracle, triggers

```
Error at line 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || indicator multiset member submultiset
```

I expect the code to automatically update the matric number on the admission status table i created.

```
create or replace trigger "TRIG_MATRIC"
after 
insert or update of STUDENT_ID, YEAR_ADMITTED, Matric_Number on "ADMISSION_STATUS"
for each row
begin
    :OLD.Student_id := :New.Student_id
    :OLD.Year_Admitted := :New.Year_Admitted
    :NEW.MATRIC_NUMBER := CONCAT(:New.Year_admitted,"/",:New.Student_id)
    Insert into Admission_Status(Matric_Number)
    values(:NEW.MATRIC_NUMBER)
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

- You cannot modify values in an `AFTER` trigger, you want a `BEFORE` trigger.
- You need to use statement terminators `;` at the end of each statement.
- You cannot modify `:OLD` values.
- `CONCAT` only takes two arguments.
- `"` quoted identifiers are considered bad practice and should be avoided wherever possible.
- You do not want to insert into the same table that your trigger is on or your code will go into an infinite loop.

It can simply be:

```sql
create or replace trigger TRIG_MATRIC
  BEFORE insert or update of STUDENT_ID, YEAR_ADMITTED, Matric_Number on ADMISSION_STATUS
  for each row
begin
    :NEW.MATRIC_NUMBER := :New.Year_admitted || '/' || :New.Student_id;
end;
/
```

---

However, don't use a trigger. If your Oracle version supports it then use a virtual column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE admission_status (
  student_id    NUMBER(8,0),
  year_admitted NUMBER(4,0),
  matric_number VARCHAR2(13) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    CAST(
      TO_CHAR(year_admitted, 'FM9990') || '/' || TO_CHAR(student_id, 'FM99999990')
      AS VARCHAR2(13)
    )
  )
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XReD8RdI)

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a try and give a feedback.